# database of products images

Tags: database, image, e-commerce, product

I'm looking for a database of images of products (e.g. iPhone, Sony TV set, a Porche car) that I can freely use in my ecommerce site. I don't wish to hotlink - I'd be happy to host the images on my site, but wish to do so legaly.

Thanks in advance for any help!

Daniel

Comment: Are you selling iPhones, Sony TV sets, or Porsches?

Answer (score 2):

Most brands make images available to the press for free. Sometimes you need to contact them and ask for images or gain access to a media site and use really official product images:

- https://presse.porsche.de/prod/presse_pag/PressResources.nsf
- http://www.apple.com/pr/products/
- http://presscentre.sony.eu/

Creative commons is also a great place to find media, often attribution is the only requirement for use:

http://search.creativecommons.org/#

Check out cnet API which will also allow you to get specs etc:

http://developer.cnet.com/docs

Cheers,